# Signed integer to signed hexadecimal 2's compliment in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample negative number in a column of a table.
e.g
-1000

Expected Output- FC18

I want the output as FC18 in oracle SQL,
which is Signed Hexadecimal 2's compliment

Reference-
https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.html?x=-1000

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_CHAR(
         CASE
         WHEN value >= POWER(2,15) OR value < -POWER(2, 15)
         THEN NULL
         WHEN value < 0
         THEN POWER(2,16)
         ELSE 0
         END + value,
         'FM000X'
       ) AS int_to_2c_hex
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT  +1000 AS value FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT  -1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT     -1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT     +1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT +32767 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -32768 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT +32768 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -32769 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | INT_TO_2C_HEX |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1000 | 03E8 |
> | -1000 | FC18 |
> | -1 | FFFF |
> | 1 | 0001 |
> | 32767 | 7FFF |
> | -32768 | 8000 |
> | 32768 | *null* |
> | -32769 | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fb7af768c6cf8a556875a123d7022d42)*